# Why won't my pages all open on my tabs bar?

Tags: html, css, tabs, blogger, blogspot

I recently have been struggling with the codeing of my new tabs bar which has all my links organized.  I thought I had finally got it, except I can not click them consecutively. My blog is: http://icantaffordmylifestyle.blogspot.com/ .  If I click the about or the contact one after another it will not work, unless I go "home"  in between navigating to different pages, yet the other links that are linked through labels on blogger are fine going through the pages, unless you click one of the "/p/" page links in between. It just keeps stacking the links.  What can I do them make them all function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using p/, every time p/ gets added to the URL, because you're implying the page is in a subdirectory of the current directory. When you use /p/ however, it will be added to the top level of your URL, resulting in your wanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your links, put a slash / in front of the p